# Latest chrome update causing bug in website layout, need help to solve the issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, layout

A website template of mine was working fine in the previous version of chrome.
But after the new update of chrome, my template is not working properly, and it works properly in every other browser....

Link to the page is:
http://nas.musemaster.net/tayn/#resume

Link to image (the error):
http://nomansamejo.com/layout.png

The scroll is not working properly in the chrome, something white appears on the content, and only redraw some of the elements...

Comment: Can you re-install the older version of chrome and see if the same issue occurs?

Comment: [Don't use the dev or beta release](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333674/4543207).. Stick with the stable

Comment: I'm sure that this issue didn't exist in the older version....

I already test it in firefox, it is working fine there.......

Comment: @Redu: is that the beta version? chrome updated automatically, also my client's browser.....

and if I'm not wrong, chrome doesn't update itself to the beta version...

Comment: No it shouldn't upgrade to beta of course.. But i know that these Google guys [have changed a lot](http://www.androidheadlines.com/2016/06/google-chrome-53-optimized-47-improvement.html) in v53 how they handled the graphics. Hmmm